# panic runtime error while fetching records from DynamoDB using golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I am facing issue while accessing aws-sdk-go, I am trying to connect to dynamo DB using aws-sdk-go. I am able to establish connection to database and insert operation is working fine, but when I am trying to retrieve data from table I am getting "panic runtime error invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference golang" error. Please find code I used. I am new to both technologies.

```
package main 
import (
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
  "github.com/user/dynamo_connect/data"
  "github.com/user/insert_api/read"
)
import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "crypto/md5"
  "encoding/hex"
  "io"
  "time"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
  router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
  router.HandleFunc("/get", GetCampaignRecord)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func GetCampaignRecord(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var testCredentials = credentials.NewStaticCredentials("AKIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "")
  sess, err := session.NewSession()
  svc := dynamodb.New(sess, &aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("ap-south-1"),
    Credentials: testCredentials,
  })

  resp, err := read.GetCampaignData(svc)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("An error occurred while writing to the Employee table")
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }

  if resp != nil {
    fmt.Println("An error occurred while writing to the Employee table")
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }
}
```

package read

```
    package read
    import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"

    func GetCampaignData(svc *dynamodb.DynamoDB) (*dynamodb.BatchGetItemOutput, error) {
      params := &dynamodb.BatchGetItemInput{
        RequestItems: map[string]*dynamodb.KeysAndAttributes{
            "employee": {
                Keys: []map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    {
                        "employee_id": {
                            S:    aws.String("1"),
                        },
                    },
                },
                ProjectionExpression: aws.String("employee_id, employee_name"),
            },
        },
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: aws.String("TOTAL"),
    }

    return svc.BatchGetItem(params)
    }
```

Full Error I am getting

> http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:36034: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>       goroutine 18 [running]:
>       net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc820102000)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
>       panic(0x8919a0, 0xc82000a110)
>        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session.(*Session).Copy(0x0, 0xc82012a020, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session/session.go:365 +0x2a
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session.(*Session).ClientConfig(0x0, 0x935410, 0x8, 0xc82012a020, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session/session.go:378 +0x72
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb.New(0x7f20477cd248, 0x0, 0xc82012a020, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc820112260)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/service.go:153 +0x78
>       main.GetCampaignRecord(0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122000, 0xc82010e000)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/user/insert_api/insert_api.go:80 +0x329
>       net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa07d38, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122000, 0xc82010e000)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
>       github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc8200125a0, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122000, 0xc82010e000)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:114 +0x2a8
>       net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc82006e180, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122000, 0xc82010e000)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
>       net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc820102000)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
>       created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
>       2016/11/19 13:31:34 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:36035: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>       goroutine 5 [running]:
>       net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc82006e200)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
>       panic(0x8919a0, 0xc82000a110)
>        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session.(*Session).Copy(0x0, 0xc82012a038, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session/session.go:365 +0x2a
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session.(*Session).ClientConfig(0x0, 0x935410, 0x8, 0xc82012a038, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session/session.go:378 +0x72
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb.New(0x7f20477cd248, 0x0, 0xc82012a038, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc820112540)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/service.go:153 +0x78
>       main.GetCampaignRecord(0x7f20477cd058, 0xc8201224e0, 0xc8200d20e0)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/user/insert_api/insert_api.go:80 +0x329
>       net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa07d38, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc8201224e0, 0xc8200d20e0)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
>       github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc8200125a0, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc8201224e0, 0xc8200d20e0)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:114 +0x2a8
>       net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc82006e180, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc8201224e0, 0xc8200d20e0)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
>       net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc82006e200)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
>       created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
>       2016/11/19 13:31:34 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:36036: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>       goroutine 34 [running]:
>       net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc820114280)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
>       panic(0x8919a0, 0xc82000a110)
>        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session.(*Session).Copy(0x0, 0xc82012a058, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session/session.go:365 +0x2a
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session.(*Session).ClientConfig(0x0, 0x935410, 0x8, 0xc82012a058, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session/session.go:378 +0x72
>       github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb.New(0x7f20477cd248, 0x0, 0xc82012a058, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc820112840)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/service.go:153 +0x78
>       main.GetCampaignRecord(0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122820, 0xc82016c000)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/user/insert_api/insert_api.go:80 +0x329
>       net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa07d38, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122820, 0xc82016c000)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
>       github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc8200125a0, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122820, 0xc82016c000)
>        /home/MyUser/work/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:114 +0x2a8
>       net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc82006e180, 0x7f20477cd058, 0xc820122820, 0xc82016c000)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
>       net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc820114280)
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
>       created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through your code and it seems to me that, there is problem with your database connectivity. You are trying to connect to maybe some different region. So, please first recheck your region. It is there in the URL of AWS account of your dynamodb.(e.g us-east-2). You can also check or configure your region by typing this command into the terminal : aws configure . Then it will ask you to enter your access key, secret key, region name etc .Enter all the details here. That's it. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @Geek_KK , Changing region solved this issue, Actually one of my colleague was trying to access these AWS credentials and he accidentally set region to default value and I was using 'ap-south-1' this region. Thanks again